# Touch/Move coordinate detection?

Tags: android

I am making a game where I must be able to know if the players finger has passed through a particular path on the screen.

How I have been doing it till now is checking if the touch coordinates of x & y is inside a vertual box that I have mapped out on the screen that has a TOP RIGHT LEFT & BOTTOM. The moment it is inside those boundaries I know the finger has passed through that area.

Is there any better logic or already some provision for the above?

Comment: Do you mean crossed the path or followed the path? And also how complex is this path, a single line or more? Code or a picture would help.

Comment: Good question should have clarified. Its a simple path from point A to point B. 1 single straight vertical line and another straight diagonal line to point C.

Comment: And do you mean crossed the path or followed the path?

Comment: Yes... I mean the finger is following the path. Perfect example would be running your finger on the image on the screen that is a road.

Comment: The chances of running your finger along the line perfectly are zero. So you must be expecting some margin of error. I think it's too vague and broad as it stands.

Comment: I agree... So I have given a play of +/-5dip. Any better logic that will help execution speed?

Comment: So you have a working solution, just slow? If so you'll need to post it to get tips on improving it.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can detect touch and click on same view using GestureDetector. Here is some code.

```
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());

private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
         // Perform click event

        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

and perform touch on your view.

```
    yourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                // single tap
                return true;
            } else {
                     // touch detetcted

                }

            }
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: This is gesture detection. I obviously know this or else I wouldn't be able to get the coordinates of the  points I'm touching. What I need is to know if there is a way to know the finger moved correctly along a particular path... Eg did the player run his finger correctly along this vertical line?